# Dynamically change the css on cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How could I dynamically change the css of a actionLink control on CSHTML page.
Suppose, I am getting a "type" parameter on the CSHTML page and on this "type" parameter basis I want to change the css of "ActionLink" on a CSHTML page.

Answer (score 0):

@Html.ActionLink("Home", "", "", null, (ViewBag.type == "your type") ? new { @class = "typeclass" } : new { @class = "otherclass" })